# Python functional transformation of JSON list of dictionaries from long to wide

Tags: python, json, functional-programming, reshape, python-itertools

I have a JSON object that I'm trying to refit to analyze differently, and I'm looking for a functional transformation to aggregate one field on the basis of two uniquely keyed fields.

My data set looks like this:

```
myjson = 

[
{
"name": "Fred",
"class": "Algebra",
"topic" : "polynomials",
"extra" : "True"
},
{
"name": "Fred",
"class": "Algebra",
"topic" : "polynomial division",
"extra" : "False"
},
{
"name": "Fred",
"class": "Algebra",
"topic" : "solving",
"extra" : "True"
},
{
"name": "Willbert",
"class": "Dance",
"topic" : "Fancy",
"extra" : "False"
},
{
"name": "Willbert",
"class": "Dance",
"topic" : "Country",
"extra" : "True"
}
]
```

I'd like to use Name and Class as unique keys for aggregating the topics field---where the contents of the "extra" field differ, I'd like them all to keep the data associated with the first entry---that is, they don't need to be merged, but should only take the value from one record.

So, I'd like to turn the above into:

```
[
{
"name": "Fred",
"class": "Algebra",
"topic" : ["polynomials","polynomial division","solving"],
"extra" : "True"
},
{
"name": "Willbert",
"class": "Dance",
"topic" : ["Fancy","Country"],
"extra" : "False"
}
]
```

Or even concatenating the topics together, as a string:

```
[
{
"name": "Fred",
"class": "Algebra",
"topic" : "polynomials polynomial division solving"
},
{
"name": "Willbert",
"class": "Dance",
"topic" : "Fancy Country"
}
]
```

I had a similar question once before [solved with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154847/correct-use-of-a-fold-or-reduce-function-to-long-to-wide-data-in-python-or-javas), but am sort of at a loss for how to start this, especially since I now have two keying entries, instead of just one.

**UPDATE**

I can get one key to get me started, which works in this example...

```
groups = itertools.groupby(myjson,lambda x: (x['name']))
[(k,list(g)) for k,g in groups]
```

But in my actual data set, 'name' alone is not sufficient to disambiguate---I need to group by 'name' and 'class.'

This does not work:

```
groups = itertools.groupby(myjson,lambda x: (x['name'],x['class']))
[(k,list(g)) for k,g in groups]
```

**UPDATE 2**

[Found this link solving a similar problem](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496726-summary-reports-using-itertoolsgroupby-extended-to/) which suggests the keying on 2 groups is non-trivial---is this really necessary, or is there another way someone more experienced with the ins and outs of itertools could point out for better using groupby?

Comment: Why is `"extra" : "True"` in the first dictionary of the result?

Comment: It's just to illustrate that there are some fields in the data set that are neither the key, nor the items I want specifically to aggregate, but that will still need to be carried over to the final one.

Comment: But it's not "carried over".  In the source records for `"Fred", "Algebra"`, it's sometime `True` and sometimes `False`.  So how would I know what value to choose?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'd like to keep the data associated with the first entry.  I think I have oversimplified a bit to make my minimal example here, but the idea is that if I actually have 10 items with the same 'name', and 'class' variables---only the first 1 of 10 actually has any data besides their 'topic' that I would like to aggregate.  For the other 9, the data fields like 'extra' are blank (or irrelevant)---so I'd like the non-empty first value to provide that data for 'extra', and ignore the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to group by some key:

```
data = {}
key = operator.itemgetter("name", "class")
for record in myjson:
    k = key(record)
    if k in data:
        data[k]["topic"].append(record["topic"])
    else:
        data[k] = record.copy()
        data[k]["topic"] = [record["topic"]]
result = data.values()
```

The loop transforms the input list into a dictionary keyed by the desired key, accumulating the `"topic"` field.  Since we include the key in the value, we can simply extract the values to get the desired result.

Comment: Does it make it substantially trickier to treat the value of 'extra' as equal to the value of the first match for each 'name' by 'class' group?

Comment: @Mittenchops: I just saw your comment and updated the solution.

Comment: @Mittenchops: Edited to correct the bug I introduced in the last edit.  Yes, it gets trickier. :)

Comment: Wow, trickiness is no problem for you, Sven.  Thanks, that's fantastic.  I see the logic now, too.  I'm glad this works so well in my quirky data format.

Comment: @Mittenchops: Another edit.  The dictionary values are all we need.