# iterative long-to-wide python one-liner (or two) using groupby

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm looking to turn a long dataset into a wide one using functional and iterative tools, and my understanding is that this is a task for groupby.  I've asked a couple of questions about this before, and thought I had it, but not quite in this case, which ought to be simpler:

- [Python functional transformation of JSON list of dictionaries from long to wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843398/python-functional-transformation-of-json-list-of-dictionaries-from-long-to-wide)
- [Correct use of a fold or reduce function to long-to-wide data in python or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154847/correct-use-of-a-fold-or-reduce-function-to-long-to-wide-data-in-python-or-javas)

Here's the data I have:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

>>> longdat=[
{"id":"cat", "name" : "best meower", "value": 10},
{"id":"cat", "name" : "cleanest paws", "value": 8},
{"id":"cat", "name" : "fanciest", "value": 9},
{"id":"dog", "name" : "smelly", "value": 9},
{"id":"dog", "name" : "dumb", "value": 9},
]
```

Here's the format I want it in:

```
>>> widedat=[
{"id":"cat", "best meower": 10, "cleanest paws": 8, "fanciest": 9},
{"id":"dog", "smelly": 9, "dumb": 9},
]
```

**Here are my failed attempts:**

```
# WRONG
>>> gh = groupby(sorted(longdat,key=id),itemgetter('id'))
>>> list(gh)
[('cat', <itertools._grouper object at 0x5d0b550>), ('dog', <itertools._grouper object at 0x5d0b210>)]
```

OK, need to get the second item out of the iterator, fair enough.

```
#WRONG
>>> gh = groupby(sorted(longdat,key=id),itemgetter('id'))
>>> for g,v in gh:
...     {"id":i["id"], i["name"]:i["value"] for i in v}
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Weird, it looked valid.  Let's unwind those loops to make sure.

```
#WRONG
gb = groupby(sorted(longdat,key=id),itemgetter('id'))
data = {}
for g,v in gb:
    data[g] = {}
    for i in v:
        data[g] = i

#WRONG
gb = groupby(sorted(longdat,key=id),itemgetter('id'))
data = []
for g,v in gb:
    for i in v:
        data[g] = i
```

Ah!  OK, let's go back to the one-line form

```
#WRONG
>>> gb = groupby(sorted(longdat,key=id),itemgetter('id'))
>>> [{"id":g, i["name"]:i["value"]} for i in k for g,k in gb]
[]
```

What?  Why empty?!  Let's unwind basically exactly this again:

```
#WRONG
gb = groupby(sorted(longdat,key=id),itemgetter('id'))
for g,k in gb:
    for i in k:
       print(g, i["name"],i["value"])
cat best meower 10
cat fanciest 9
cat cleanest paws 8
dog smelly 9
dog dumb 9
```

Now, this last one is obviously the worst---it's clear my data is basically right back where it started, as if I didn't even groupby.

Why is this not working and how can I get this in the format I'm seeking?

Also, is it possibly to phrase this entirely iteratively such that I could do

```
>>> result[0]
{"id":"cat", "best meower": 10, "cleanest paws": 8, "fanciest": 9}
```

and only get the first result without processing the entire list (beyond having to look at /all/ where id == 'cat'?)

Comment: Thanks for describing your problem with words, examples, and showing what you've researched and attempted. A question this well-written is a rarity on SO these days.

Comment: Thanks, IceArdor.  Folks usually just call it unnecessarily verbose.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` function passed to the `sorted` function is [`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id). It will return all different values for all list items.

It should be `itemgetter('id')` or `lambda x: x.id`.

```
>>> id(longdat[0])
41859624L
>>> id(longdat[1])
41860488L
>>> id(longdat[2])
41860200L
>>> itemgetter('id')(longdat[1])
'cat'
>>> itemgetter('id')(longdat[2])
'cat'
>>> itemgetter('id')(longdat[3])
'cat'
```

---

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

longdat = [
    {"id":"cat", "name" : "best meower", "value": 10},
    {"id":"cat", "name" : "cleanest paws", "value": 8},
    {"id":"cat", "name" : "fanciest", "value": 9},
    {"id":"dog", "name" : "smelly", "value": 9},
    {"id":"dog", "name" : "dumb", "value": 9},
]

getid = itemgetter('id')
result = [
    dict([['id', key]] + [[d['name'], d['value']] for d in grp])
    for key, grp in groupby(sorted(longdat, key=getid), key=getid)
]
print(result)
```

output:

```
[{'best meower': 10, 'fanciest': 9, 'id': 'cat', 'cleanest paws': 8},
 {'dumb': 9, 'smelly': 9, 'id': 'dog'}]
```

Comment: What am I missing when I try to replace your dict([[ ]] + [[ ] ]) syntax with `[{'id':key, d['name']:d['value'] for d in grp} for key,grp in gb]`  Shouldn't that be the same just with the {} constructor rather than the dict() function?

Comment: @Mittenchops, Do you mean dict comprehension? I have no idea how to do it using dict comprehension without using iterating [[..]] + [[..]] or `itertools.chain...`

Comment: @Mittenchops, If you want to use dict comprehension, see [this](http://ideone.com/To88FA). It's little bit more longer, btw.

Comment: @Mittenchops, FYI, [Here's a non-one-liner version](http://ideone.com/nWr6DR) (easier to read)

Comment: Interesting, it didn't occur to me that that was constructing the list iterator as it went.

Comment: @Mittenchops, Sorry, I'm not a good Englisher reader. I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @Mittenchops, The code in the answer create list by concatenating single element list and list generated by list comprehension.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was just trying to understand why what I thought were two equivalent syntaxes were working differently, and it was because, I think, there is one more iterator in that I didn't notice the list comprehension.

Comment: @Mittenchops, Ah, I missed your last question: `only get the first result without processing the entire list` -> use `break` if you use simple `for` loop.

Comment: @Mittenchops, If you use ANY comprehension, use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice): See http://ideone.com/TJiQ1c

Comment: This does seem a little circuitous, right?  It seems like I'm using groupby to split this into the groups, but then breaking it right back down to the original format as I loop over the groupby.  As in, if I read the flow correctly, I'm pretty sure the first line of the dict comprehension formulation is just undoing the groupby done in the second line, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48381/discussion-between-falsetru-and-mittenchops)